# Android Send SMS Address and Body in the web service one by one

Tags: java, android, sms

I am facing some issue, i am getting the sms body and address, and send that sms body/address in the web services, but when web service is called, the value is duplicated, i am facing the following issue:

1- every time if i have 3 messages in my inbox then the loop will be run 3 times and also there is one messages will be sending again and again in the web service.

2- i want that when i am get the sms body and address then asyn task will be called and async task run till the end, after first iteration then again asyncall will be called for 2nd iteration and so on.

i know my question is so much confusing but plz help, any help will be higly appreciated, below is my code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
            null, null, null, null);

    int count = 0;

    int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.BODY);
    int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS);

    if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst())
        return;

    smsList.clear();

    do {
        strmobilenum = cursor.getString(indexAddr);
        // str = "0" + str.substring(3);
        strmessagebody = cursor.getString(indexBody);
        String mb = strmobilenum;
        String mbody = strmessagebody;
        //SendSMSToServer();
        new AsyncCallWS().execute();
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


            PropertyInfo unameProp = new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("SMSSenderMobileNo");// Define the variable name in
                String mobnum = strmobilenum;                                   // the web // service method
            unameProp.setValue(strmobilenum);// set value for userName variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);// Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(unameProp);// Pass properties to the variable

            PropertyInfo textProp = new PropertyInfo();
            textProp.setName("SMSText");// Define the variable name in the web //
                        String msgbody = strmessagebody;                // service method
            textProp.setValue(strmessagebody);// set value for userName variable
            textProp.setType(String.class);// Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(textProp);// Pass properties to the variable

            // SSLConection.allowAllSSL();
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            // androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);



            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            String jsonResponse = "";
            jsonResponse = response.toString();

            // A JSONTokener is needed in order to use JSONObject correctly
            JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(jsonResponse);
            // Pass a JSONTokener to the JSONObject constructor
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);
            JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("FeedSMS");

            if (data != null) {

                // looping through All nodes
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    RetVal = c.getString("RetVal");
                    RetDes = c.getString("RetDes");

                }

                /*
                 * Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success",
                 * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 */

            } else {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // alertDialog(e.toString());
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        // tv.setText(fahren + "° F");

        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (RetVal != null) {

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (RetVal.equalsIgnoreCase("T")) {

                alertDialog(RetDes);

            } else {

                alertDialog(RetDes);

            }
        } else {
            //alertDialog("server error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Sending SMS...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the index outside the while loop

```
int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.BODY);
int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS);

if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst())
    return;
```

above indexBody and indexAddr will always contain the values for the first sms as the cursor position is 0 for the first time. 
Write the above code in the **do loop** as below

```
do
{
    int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.BODY);
    int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS);
    if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst())
        return;
    strmobilenum = cursor.getString(indexAddr);
    // str = "0" + str.substring(3);
    strmessagebody = cursor.getString(indexBody);
    String mb = strmobilenum;
    String mbody = strmessagebody;
    //SendSMSToServer();
    new AsyncCallWS().execute();
}
```

Comment: i just want to that 1st sms body send in the web service succesfully, after succesfully sending 1st sms then 2nd will be send in the web service and so on until all sms are read and send to the web service.

Comment: There must be some easier way of achieving it but as far as i know what you can do is, get all the numbers and sms body from cursor and store in an arraylist. Then start your asyncTask adding the value from arraylist, when in response you get statusCode  = 200, call asyncTask again with next position in arraylist

Comment: did you find the answer useful? If yes then please accept the answer and if not then can you tell me how did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes i have found the solution, and i will must share the solution when i got a time.Thanks for your help.